# Can "multiply" be used with uncountable nouns?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

If *multiply* means to

> increase or cause to increase greatly in number ***or quantity*** ([OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=multiply%20meaning&sxsrf=ALiCzsZ9p34R_nD7f_NSNLMQC1OpZ6AV3g%3A1660389642587&ei=Con3Yv66I4nMgAa6vavQCg&oq=multiply%20mea&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADIKCAAQkQIQRhD5ATIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDoHCAAQRxCwAzoECCMQJzoECAAQQzoICAAQsQMQkQI6BQgAEJECOg4ILhCABBDHARCvARDUAkoECEEYAEoECEYYAFDEBFiLHWDVJWgBcAF4AIABYIgBswKSAQE0mAEAoAEByAEHwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz))

does that mean that ***multiply*** can be used with uncountable nouns as well? Most examples I find are with countable nouns.

I know it's best to say

> increase awareness

but can you *multiply* it too? Can you *multiply gratitude*? *Love*?

I see it could in the KJV Bible:

> Mercy unto you, and peace, and love, be ***multiplied***. (Jude 1:2 KJV)

It does sound uncommon, I know. Is this because of the word forming element ***[multi-/mult-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/multi-?ref=etymonline_crossreference)*** which means ***many***?

Comment: @BenjaminHarman I am translating this passage which says something like "This would have only multiplied his gratitude and love", but when I wrote this it sounded odd to my ears, so I began wondering... But asking the question here and reading your comments, I begin to understand that the sentence would sound much better in the passive. Plus, in the vast majority of the examples on the web, multiply is used with countable nouns, so I wondered if its use with uncountable nouns was dated or forced... but you seem not to think so, so I am reassured.

Answer (score 1):

You can not only "multiply your income" (600K results in google web search) , you can also "divide your income" (200K results in google web search)

You can not only "multiply your happiness" (200K results) , you can also "divide your happiness" (300K results)

> Proven ways to "Multiply your income" in a year ...

> The basic rule of thumb is to "Divide your income" into three spending categories ...

> The best way to "Multiply your happiness" is to share it with others ...

> When you "Divide your happiness" you will still remain with the same amount ...

We can Answer the title of the Question with Yes.

I am sure there are Income Estimators & Happiness Calculators , but that is out of the scope of this Question.